# Execute docker host command inside jenkins docker container

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have a docker container running jenkins. I want inside this container to start other container, so outside this container.

I've tried to start my jenkins controller with :

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  -v $(which docker):/bin/docker
```

( As written here : https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/ )

But when inside of my container I try to run a Docker command, I have the typical message

```
 FATA[0000] Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.18/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: 
connect: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

And no way to run docker command inside this container..

I've tried with and without --privileged=true, it still don't work.

If you have any ideas !

Comment: did you try to add "sudo" before the command ? Or make sure the service is running "sudo service docker start". Or add your user to the group : "sudo usermod -aG docker username" then log out or restart to take effect.

Comment: I am running into a similar issue as well, with a different error: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

Answer (score 2):

A related post to this issue is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072491/jenkins-in-docker-with-access-to-host-docker?rq=1).

However, a few words on this (as I had the same issue). There are two things you need to do: (1) mount `docker.sock` and (2) have `docker` service running.

Regarding (1): As mentioned by @yclian you have to put the `jenkins` user into the `docker` group.

I followed [Adrian Mouat's instruction](http://container-solutions.com/running-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/). He suggests to execute docker commands in a build step with `sudo docker run ..`. The `sudo` is fine in my scenario, but in general it may be a security issue in that the Jenkins user may get root access to the host and could create containers that mount arbitrary directories on the host.

Regarding (2) and `-v $(which docker):/bin/docker` in your command. I'm on MacOS. `which docker` gives me `/usr/local/bin/docker/` which is correct, but still `docker` was not available inside the container. I started the jenkins container with

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /Users/matthaeus/.jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -t -i jenkins
```

If you do not want to do this you have to install the `docker engine` inside the container, either manually by connecting to it (`docker exec -t -i container-id /bin/bash` and `apt-get install docker-engine`) or specifying it in a `Dockerfile`.

If you have done both your build steps may contain the commands like this `sudo docker build -t my-image .` and this image will also be available on the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

When such situation happens, first have a look at the `/var/run/docker.sock` it's dialing. If I'm not wrong, you will have to put your `jenkins` user into the `docker` group in order to have access to the socket file.

Would also be good to troubleshoot this by logging into the shell as `jenkins` user, vs. troubleshooting via Jenkins UI.