# How to run circleci locally on macOS with a job that uses Docker?

Tags: docker, circleci

I have run into an issue when trying to run `circleci build` locally on macOS when trying to build a docker image.

Example .config file

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/base:2020.01
    steps:
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run:
          name: Run Docker
          command: docker run cimg/base:2020.01 echo "hello"
```

After running `circleci build`

`failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

I've looked at several similar questions such as [this one](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/how-to-run-docker-build-in-a-circleci-job-that-uses-docker/21075/5) but none of their solutions work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to adapt the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999000/permission-denied-error-invoking-docker-on-mac-host-from-inside-docker-ubuntu-co) to work with circleci.

Simply add the command `sudo chown circleci:circleci /var/run/docker.sock` to your circle config.

So it will look like:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/base:2020.01
    steps:
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run: if [ -e /var/run/docker.sock ]; then sudo chown circleci:circleci /var/run/docker.sock; fi
      - run:
          name: Run Docker
          command: docker run cimg/base:2020.01 echo "hello"
```

And the result

```
====>> Run Docker
  #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
docker run cimg/base:2020.01 echo "hello"
hello
Success!
```